# Batch File Won't Run - Command Line Script Does

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ftp

I am using an ncftp script to upload some files via ftp. I want to automate this process so I am using a batch file to run it. Here is my script:

```
ncftpput -u myusername -p mypassword -R myftpaddress /remotefolder "C:\Users\myusername\Google Drive\*"
```

It runs perfectly when I just paste it into the command line. But as a batch file, it does absolutely nothing. I can see the command window open very briefly and then it just exits.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Batch files strip out percentage signs from their contents unless you use two in a row. For example, if you wanted to display "5%" you would need "5%%" in your batch file. I had a percentage sign in my password and so it wasn't working.

Strangely, even after I added a "pause" at the end of my file and took a look at what it was saying, it never said anything about a wrong password; it just didn't run anything. Weird.